# cypress tests. How to test deeplink

Tags: reactjs, testing, cypress, e2e-testing

I have one issue with cypress test.
I have such test

```
const deeplinkUrl = 'https://deeplink.page.link/2WmRA4zbfUcQz5AY9';

describe('upload scan view', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.visit('/deplinkPage');
    cy.injectAxe();
  });

  it('should redirect user to deep link', () => {
    cy.waitForLoaderRemoval();
    cy.getEnabledButton('Install for Free');
    cy.get('body').compareSnapshot('upload-scan-view');

    cy.get('button').contains('Install for Free').trigger('click');
    cy.url().should('be.equals', deeplinkUrl);
  });
});
```

I have issue every time I am clicking on button with `deeplink`. My test fails because cypress waits for page to be loaded and every time it checks url there is different url because `deepllink` have redirection to app store or it will redirect you to app with totally different url. And because of that after page load event there is different link
I need to check that after clicking button users url is my `deeplink` which is there for some short time after clicking

Answer (score 3):

Can you catch the link with an intercept?

This should work as long as the app you are testing fires off the request to `deeplinkUrl`.

```js
cy.intercept(deeplinkUrl).as('deepLink')

cy.get('button').contains('Install for Free').click()  

cy.wait('@deeplink')
```

Adding `req.destroy()` will stop the ***redirect*** happening if that is getting in the way of your test.

Or if you just wish to ***delay*** the redirect, add a `setTimeout()`.

```js
cy.intercept(deeplinkUrl, (req) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    req.continue()
  }, 2000)
}).as('deepLink')

cy.get('button').contains('Install for Free').click()  

cy.wait('@deeplink')
```

Comment: where are you using `deepLinkWasCaught ? can't see that in yours example

Comment: I simplified the intercept, that's no longer needed (but still got pasted into the code).

Comment: thanks. this did not helped :/ after click and setting urp to my deeplink, still cypress is waiting for "page loaded" event. thanks for help

Comment: Oh that's a shame, it works for me.

Answer (score -2):

You can introduce a custom command that waits for the URL to match your deeplink. Here's an example of how you can modify your code:

```
const deeplinkUrl = 'https://deeplink.page.link/2WmRA4zbfUcQz5AY9';

describe('upload scan view', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.visit('/deplinkPage');
    cy.injectAxe();
  });

  // Custom command to wait for the URL to match the expected deeplink
  Cypress.Commands.add('waitForDeeplink', (expectedUrl) => {
    cy.url().should('include', expectedUrl);
  });

  it('should redirect user to deep link', () => {
    cy.waitForLoaderRemoval();
    cy.getEnabledButton('Install for Free');
    cy.get('body').compareSnapshot('upload-scan-view');

    cy.get('button').contains('Install for Free').click();

    // Wait for the deeplink URL
    cy.waitForDeeplink(deeplinkUrl);
  });
});
```

Comment: did you use any generative AI at all in the writing of this answer post?